# TypeError when calling dynamic_rnn on LSTMCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm kind of new to working with TensorFlow and my problem may be easy to solve, at least I hope so.
I'm trying to work with LSTMCell to predict the next label in a sequence.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
import tensorflow as tf

max_sequence_length = 1000
vector_length = 1
number_of_classes = 1000
batch_size = 50
num_hidden = 24

# Define graph
data = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, max_sequence_length, vector_length])
# 0 must be a free class so that the mask can work
target = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, max_sequence_length, number_of_classes + 1])
labels = tf.argmax(target, 2)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)
```

Then I try to get the real length of each sequence in the batch

```
no_of_batches = tf.shape(data)[0]

sequence_lengths = tf.zeros([batch_size])
for i in xrange(max_sequence_length):
    data_at_t = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(data, [0,i,0],[-1,1,-1]))
    t = tf.scalar_mul(i, tf.ones([batch_size]))
    boolean = tf.not_equal(data_at_t, tf.zeros([no_of_batches, batch_size], dtype = tf.int64))
    sequence_lengths = tf.select(boolean, t, sequence_lengths)
```

And finally I try to call tf.nn.dynamic_rnn :

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell = cell,
    inputs = data,
    sequence_length = max_sequence_length,
    dtype = tf.float64
    )
```

Then, I get a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 830, in dynamic_rnn
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 997, in _dynamic_rnn_loop
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1973, in while_loop
    result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1860, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 1810, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 980, in _time_step
    skip_conditionals=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 394, in _rnn_step
    new_output, new_state = call_cell()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 968, in <lambda>
    call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 489, in __call__
    dtype, self._num_unit_shards)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 323, in _get_concat_variable
    sharded_variable = _get_sharded_variable(name, shape, dtype, num_shards)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py", line 353, in _get_sharded_variable
    dtype=dtype))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 830, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 673, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 217, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 202, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 536, in _get_single_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 211, in __init__
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 281, in _init_from_args
    self._initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(initial_value(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 526, in <lambda>
    init_val = lambda: initializer(shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py", line 210, in _initializer
    dtype, seed=seed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py", line 235, in random_uniform
    minval = ops.convert_to_tensor(minval, dtype=dtype, name="min")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 621, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 180, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 163, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 353, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 290, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int64, got -0.34641016151377546 of type 'float' instead.
```

I don't understand where this float comes from as all other values in the script are integers. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1) The RNN cell state is **tf.float64**. You set this explicitly within the **tf.nn.dynamic_rnn** call (dtype). The tensorflow engine then initialized the states with RNN's default random_uniform initializer. This is why you have the -0.34 float value there.

I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve. Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn

2) The `sequence_length = max_sequence_length` must be an int32/int64 vector sized [batch_size] instead of scalar 1000

3) You may want to initialize the LSTMCell state too:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True), 
    initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0, dtype=tf.int32))
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar problem with my code, i fixed it by replacing the int32 at the placeholder as float, check if that works